# C# Expression Tree to call base class property get method

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.5, expression-trees

I have built an expression tree that derives parameters from a class and invokes them to set values in another class. It works very well for most types, but it fails on a derived type. If I have:

```
public class A
{
    public string MyString {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class B : A
{

}
```

If I use this Expression Tree code (where `value` is the derived instance):

```
// Get the type of the object for caching and ExpressionTree purposes
var objectType = value.GetType();
// Define input parameter
var inputObject = Expression.Parameter( typeof( object ), "value" );

var properties = objectType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public );
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Expression.Property( Expression.ConvertChecked( inputObject, property.DeclaringType ), property.GetGetMethod() )
}
```

I will receive this exception:

```
{System.ArgumentException: The method 'My.Namespace.A.get_MyString' is not a property accessor
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetProperty(MethodInfo mi)...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use property itself and not Getter method for it:

```
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Expression.Property( 
         Expression.ConvertChecked( inputObject, property.DeclaringType ),
         property);
}
```

Basically you need to use this [Property method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of this overloaded [Property method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302663%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**UPDATE**

For GetGetMethod approach - If `var objectType` equal to `A` type, then it works. If it equal to `B` type, then it doesn't work.

My guess, that the problem is in `property.DeclaringType`. For both cases it's `A` type, as property declared in it. But this code will return different `ReflectedType` for the same property:

```
var reflectingTypeForA = typeof(A).GetProperty("MyString").GetGetMethod().ReflectedType;
var reflectingTypeForB = typeof(B).GetProperty("MyString").GetGetMethod().ReflectedType;
```

For `A` it returns `A`, and for `B` type it returns `B`. My guess is that for `B` case Expression.Property logic checks that `property.DeclaringType` is `A`, but GetGetMethod has `ReflectedType` equal to `B`, so it thinks that it's property of another object. I haven't any proofs for that, but only these members are different between two GetGetMethod calls

**UPDATE2**

Here is a code that used by Expression.Property(MethodInfo method):

```
private static PropertyInfo GetProperty(MethodInfo mi)
{
    Type type = mi.DeclaringType;
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    flags |= (mi.IsStatic) ? BindingFlags.Static : BindingFlags.Instance;
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(flags);
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
    {
        if (pi.CanRead && CheckMethod(mi, pi.GetGetMethod(true)))
        {
            return pi;
        }
        if (pi.CanWrite && CheckMethod(mi, pi.GetSetMethod(true)))
        {
            return pi;
        }
    }
    throw new SomeException();
}

private static bool CheckMethod(MethodInfo method, MethodInfo propertyMethod) { 
    if (method == propertyMethod) {
        return true; 
    } 
    // If the type is an interface then the handle for the method got by the compiler will not be the
    // same as that returned by reflection. 
    // Check for this condition and try and get the method from reflection.
    Type type = method.DeclaringType;
    if (type.IsInterface && method.Name == propertyMethod.Name && type.GetMethod(method.Name) == propertyMethod) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
if (method == propertyMethod) {
    return true; 
}
```

When you get MethodInfo by GetGetMethod from Type `A`, it's different than MethodInfo from Type `B`, and this check returns false.
Such example also returns false:

```
var propertyAGetter = typeof(A).GetProperty("MyString").GetGetMethod();
var propertyBGetter = typeof(B).GetProperty("MyString").GetGetMethod();
bool areTheSame = propertyAGetter == propertyBGetter; // it equals to false
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I'll give you the answer if you can tell me WHY it worked because I don't understand and it kills me not to understand my code!

Comment: added my guess into answer :)

Comment: Damn, great answer. Thank you @Sergey - really appreciate it. I wonder if this is technically a bug in the .NET framework?

Comment: technically these two objects are different because of ReflectedType. So, it's not a bug. Here is an answer about ReflectedType given by Jon Skeet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276271/why-is-a-member-of-base-class-different-from-the-same-member-in-derived-class

Comment: I disagree with their design decision regarding `ReflectedType`, but at least now I understand why my code was breaking. :)

Comment: It still seems like a bug that `Expression.Property` accepts a `PropertyInfo` with a derived `ReflectedType`, but not a `MethodInfo` with one.

Comment: @nmclean I agree. Seems wrong but maybe there's a use case we aren't thinking of.